# displaying x amount of records using limit

Tags: php, html

I'm using working on a query that displays user id and the problem i'm having is, its able to retrive all the data excluding the last record. For example i have these id's (1,2,3,4,5).
With my script its able to retrieve from 5 to 2 ignoring 1.

```
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_vivalooks, $vivalooks);
$query_rs_resq = "SELECT user_id FROM users_pics ORDER BY profile_id desc LIMIT 0,5; ";
$rs_resq = mysql_query($query_rs_resq, $vivalooks) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_resq = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_resq);
$totalRows_rs_resq = mysql_num_rows($rs_resq);
```

HTLM & PHP

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
<?php
    if($totalRows_rs_resq > 0){ 
         while($row_rs_resq =  mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_resq)){ 
         $u_pic_id = $row_rs_resq['u_pic_id'];
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_rs_resq['u_pic_id']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

with my script instead of displaying 5 records, only 4 appears.

Comment: Is your query definitely returning 5 results?

Comment: Just a super dumb comment maybe, but are you certain that there are more than 5 records in the database?

Comment: yes about 600 records

Comment: Have you tried it without the offset parameter? i.e. LIMIT 5;

Comment: And does the mysql_num_rows definitely report 4?

Comment: Additionally why are you performing this operation more than once? $row_rs_resq =  mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_resq). Remove one of them, it may be the case that the result is being popped prior to the second operation, hence 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is the fact that you have two statements performing the same operation.

```
$row_rs_resq =  mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_resq);
```

Remove one of them as when it performs this it is moving the internal pointer of the array. It's either that or you reset the internal pointer.

See: [mysql_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row as an associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)